# Printing In MFC Application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

How can I print a document using MFC Dialog Based Application? I have made a print button. After clicking on this button, I want print of some document or some text.

Comment: What does your MFC book say to do next? What have you tried?

Comment: http://www.codersource.net/mfc/mfc-tutorials/mfc-print-tutorial.aspx But Still confused on how to start proceeding as it is not dialog based application

Comment: Which document? Specific on every click or the user needs to browse first?

Comment: No need to browse. File path will be hardcoded. Or if it is possible to browse, then also OK. I just want to print a text Document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an invisble `CHtmlEditCtrl` control and load your text to it with `SetDocumentHTML(LPCTSTR)` method and then call `PrintDocument()` method.

```
void WaitForComplete(IHTMLDocument2* document)
{
    BSTR ready;
    document->get_readyState(&ready);
    while(wcscmp(ready, L"complete"))
    {
        AfxPumpMessage();
        document->get_readyState(&ready);
    };
}

void CPrintInMFCDialogBasedAppDlg::OnBnClickedPrint()
{
    CHtmlEditCtrl PrintCtrl;
    if(!PrintCtrl.Create(NULL, WS_CHILD, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 1))
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
        return; // Error!
    }
    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> document;
    PrintCtrl.GetDocument(&document);
    WaitForComplete(document);
    PrintCtrl.SetDocumentHTML(_T("Hello!<BR>It is <B>my first</B> print!"));
    WaitForComplete(document);
    PrintCtrl.PrintDocument();
}
```

Comment: can u give some example or link where i can find this?